# Webview not loading poupup - ReactNative

Tags: webview, react-native

In react native the webview is not loading any popup. Also `_onShouldStartLoadWithRequest`, `_onNavigationStateChange`, `_renderError` not logging any events when I try to show popup window.

Below is my render method.

```
  render() {
      const finalURL='xyz';
      return(
           <WebView
               source={{uri:finalURL}}
               javaScriptEnabled={true}
               domStorageEnabled={true}
               onLayout={this._onLayout}
               onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={this._onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
               onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange}
               startInLoadingState={true}
               renderError={this._renderError}
             />
    );
  }
```

Any suggestion on how to show pupup.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue? If yes can you provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As per React Native documentation on webview component
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#onshouldstartloadwithrequest

onShouldStartLoadWithRequest prop works only on iOS and it should return a true or false value either to continue loading the request or stop loading.

```
  _onShouldStartLoadWithRequest() {
    return true
  }
```